# TCPDF v.6.2.13 runs well if its file-based cache-folder gets rwx-rights (in no.: 7) for public

Tags: php, security, caching, apache2, tcpdf

As others have told in the past, TCPDF wants to cache some data into an file-system based cache on the webserver. My issue here is: my TCPDF ran well as long as i tested it locally on my apache2 server with folder cache under 744 rights, what is no problem there. When i tried to set it up to run via http and browser, i had to chmod (change) the cache-folder from 744 to 755 (what didn't succeed, and produced 4 warnings like that one:

"Warning: imagepng(): Unable to open '/var/www/html/platzhalter.One/tcPDFv6213/cache/__tcpdf_e9510f8b9d774b0fe1a483b45591b1b2_imgmask_alpha_1bb87d41d15fe27b500a4bfcde01bb0e' for writing: Permission denied ..." )

All warnings could only be stopped by chmod 777. That's my issue. Should i, if i want to use TCPDF, what i'd like to, provide others with the rights, to write, delete and execute within "my" cache? Has it not stopped to be "my" cache under these conditions?

tcPDFv6213 # ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root        4096 Jun  6 14:34 cache

Comment: It's been a long time since I used tcpdf, so I don't know why it needs 777. But be aware that if you set it like that, any user on your Linux will be able to read and arbitrarily modify generated pdfs, which may be a significant risk.

Comment: thank you, gabor, for that. i am aware, but the 777 is only for the the tcpdf cache folder. i don't know what that means in terms of security in detail: ...